# Python: Incorporating file path in put requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working on a project that uses the requests library and communicates with Autodesk Forge REST APIs. In a part of this project, I have to upload a file to the server. I am using the code below:

```
url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/' + BUCKET_NAME + '/objects/' + FILE_NAME
headers = {
'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN,
}

with open(FILE_NAME, 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=f)
```

Where BUCKET_NAME is the name of the bucket and FILE_NAME is the name of the file I want to upload. In case the file that I want to upload is in the same directory as the python script, this code works fine. However, is there any way I can provide a PATH to a file? (for example, how do I make this code work when the FILE_NAME is /dir1/dir2/dir3/filename.jpg)?

Comment: Maybe `url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/' + BUCKET_NAME + '/objects/' + FILE_NAME.replace('/', '_')` will be enough to do the trick?

Comment: is it linux or windows?

Comment: The operating system is Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create your path and assign to `FILE_NAME`, note that this works only on linux systems since we have `/` as path separator

```
import os

folders = ['dir1','dir2','dir3']
FILE_NAME = os.path.join(*folders, 'filename.jpg')

print(FILE_NAME)
```

For a more generic approach, we can simply join the individual directories and file name using `/` as separator

```
names = ['dir1','dir2','dir3', 'filename.jpg']

FILE_NAME = '/'.join(names)
print(FILE_NAME)
```

The output in both cases will be

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/filename.jpg
```